# How to save shared data in tkinter for python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm very new to the world of GUIs with Python and attempting to build my first one with multiple pages, but sharing a variable from an entry box is really throwing me through a loop. I understand there's probably a lot wrong with the code, but for now, I would really just like to better understand how to share the variables between the pages from the username entry box.

Here is the code that ties into this:(The page breaks are just where there is some unrelated code)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, StringVar

class Keep(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.shared_data ={
            "email": tk.StringVar(),
            "password": tk.StringVar()
        }
# Skipping some code to get to the good stuff

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        # LABELS, ENTRIES, AND BUTTONS

        # page break

        self.entry1 = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["email"])
        entry2 = tk.Entry(self, show = '*')
        button1 = tk.Button(text="Submit", command=lambda: [controller.show_frame("PageTwo"), self.retrieve()])

    # page break

    def retrieve(self):
        self.email = self.controller.shared_data["email"].get()
        self.controller.email = self.email

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.email = self.controller.shared_data["email"].get()

        label1 = tk.Label(self, text="Welcome, {}".format(self.email))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    keep = Keep()
    keep.mainloop()
```

I know the retrieve function looks pretty funky and probably not at all correct, but I've been working on this specific problem for about a week now and it has lead me down some wild rabbit holes.

The end goal is for `label1` of `pageTwo` to display, "Welcome, (insert e-mail entered in `entry1` of `startPage`)".

I think my issue lies with `pageTwo` retrieving an empty string from `shared_data`, but I don't understand why that is.

Any help is super appreciated!

Comment: You show `PageTwo` *before* calling `.retrieve()`, so the retrieved data is not available when initializing the page.

Comment: you removed too many lines and now we can't run it to see problem.

Comment: because these classes are very popular on SO so I can guess that problem is because classes are created at start in `Keep.__init__` so `PageTwo.__init__` is executed at start, not when you run `show_frame`, so `Welcome, ...` is created at start, not when you run `show_frame()`. You should have method `update_widgets()` in classes which updates text in labels/entries and you should run this `update_widgets()` after `show_frame()` or run `update_widgets()` inside `show_frame()` if all classes will have `update_widgets()`. And don't use name `update()` because `tkinter` already uses this name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess problem is because frames are created in `Keep.__init__`, not when you run `show_frame()`, so `PageTwo.__init__()` is executed at start and text `Welcome...` is create at start - before you even see `StartPage`.

You should create empty label in `__init__` and create text `Welcome...` in other method (ie. `update_widgets()`) which you will execute after `show_frame()` or event inside `show_frame()` if all classes will have `update_widgets()`>

---

Minimal working code:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Keep(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.shared_data ={
            "email": tk.StringVar(),
            "password": tk.StringVar()
        }

        self.frames = {
            'StartPage': StartPage(self, self),
            'PageTwo': PageTwo(self, self),
        }

        self.current_frame = None
        self.show_frame('StartPage')

    def show_frame(self, name):
        if self.current_frame:
            self.current_frame.forget()
        self.current_frame = self.frames[name]
        self.current_frame.pack()

        self.current_frame.update_widgets() # <-- update data in widgets


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.controller = controller

        self.entry1 = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["email"])
        self.entry1.pack()
        entry2 = tk.Entry(self, show='*')
        entry2.pack()
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Submit", command=lambda:controller.show_frame("PageTwo"))
        button.pack()

    def update_widgets(self):
        pass

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.controller = controller

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="") # <-- create empty label
        self.label.pack()

    def update_widgets(self):
        self.label["text"] = "Welcome, {}".format(self.controller.shared_data["email"].get()) # <-- update text in label


if __name__ == "__main__":
    keep = Keep()
    keep.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks so much! The code does what I want now. I didn't provide large chunks of code because it definitely needs some cleaning up but that specific part was eating away at me.