# Keeping values from one Tkinter frame to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, tkinter

I am trying to pass variable values from one frame to another in Tkinter, but it's returning empty value.

Class A:

```
class a(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.controller=controller


    self.logVar=tk.StringVar()

    tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.logVar,width=4,show="*").grid(row=1,column=1)
```

Class B:

```
class b(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self,parent,controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
    self.controller=controller
    frame=controller.frames['a']
    pin=frame.logVar.get()
    print(pin)
    tk.Label(self,text=pin).grid(row=0,column=1)
```

No Errors were displayed, instead, it's just returning an empty string.

Comment: frames are create at start - before you even see window - so it get value from Entry before you put text in Entry. You have to create function which get value and run it when you change frame. Few days ago was similar question.

Comment: [How to save shared data in tkinter for python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58350259/how-to-save-shared-data-in-tkinter-for-python)